# How to remove interstitial google Ads manually in IONIC 4

Tags: ionic-framework, interstitial

I need to display interstitial Google Ads on click of a button. After 3 seconds timeout, I need to close interstitial Google Ads and display routing screen.

I have opened interstitial Google Ads. But I won't be able to close it.

```
  displayAds(page) {
    let interstitialConfig: AdMobFreeInterstitialConfig = {
      isTesting: true,
      autoShow: true
    };
    this.admob.interstitial.config(interstitialConfig);
    this.admob.interstitial.prepare().then(() => {
    }).catch(e => alert(e));
  }
```